# image overlay and change on dropdown selection?

Tags: html, overlay

I'd like to make something of this kind where you can select the fore and background and make it display together. : https://www.control4.com/solutions/products/switches

I do understand some things could be missing and I have tried to look around. I'd appreciate any help. Many thanks.

```
<div class="foreground">
  <h4>Button Colour</h4>
    <select onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="switch/button/white.png" selected>White</option>
        <option value="switch/button/snowwhite.png">Snow White</option>
        <option value="switch/button/biscuit.png">Biscuit</option>
        <option value="switch/button/lightalmond.png">Light Almond</option>
        <option value="switch/button/brown.png">Brown</option>
        <option value="switch/button/black.png">Black</option>
        <option value="switch/button/midnightblack.png">Midnight Black</option>
        <option value="switch/button/aluminum.png">Aluminum</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<div class="background">
    <h4>Faceplate Colour</h4>
    <select onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="switch/faceplate/white.png" selected>White</option>
        <option value="switch/faceplate/snowwhite.png">Snow White</option>
        <option value="switch/faceplate/biscuit.png">Biscuit</option>
        <option value="switch/faceplate/lightalmond.png">Light Almond</option>
        <option value="switch/faceplate/brown.png">Brown</option>
        <option value="switch/faceplate/black.png">Black</option>
        <option value="switch/faceplate/midnightblack.png">Midnight Black</option>
        <option value="switch/faceplate/aluminum.png">Aluminum</option>
        <option value="switch/faceplate/satinnickle.png">Satin Nickel</option>
        <option value="switch/faceplate/bronze.png">Venetian Bronze</option>
        <option value="switch/faceplate/stainlesssteel.png">Stainless Steel</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
  <!-- style -->
  <style type="text/css">
    .background { 
       position:absolute;
      z-index:1;
      left:125px;
      top:125px;
      float: right;
    }

    .foreground {   
      position:absolute;
      z-index:auto;
      float: left;
    } 

   #switch{
    position: relative;
   }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, those images are png and of same dimensions with perfectly positioned switch and background. so displaying one div inside another will overlap it perfectly as the snippet below

Something with jQuery, should get you going....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#switchSel').change(function() {

    var switchPic = $('.switch');
    switchPic.removeClass();
    switchPic.addClass('switch ' + $(this).val());
  })
})
```

```css
.back {
  background: url(https://www.control4.com/files/large/805347005e9b7ee87d4da29d56c9fa44.png);
  height: 575px;
  width: 361px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.brown {
  background: url(https://www.control4.com/files/large/61ba4092e170c22c3806a930ca7924f5.png);
  height: 575px;
  width: 361px;
}
.black {
  background: url(https://www.control4.com/files/large/251e9a5ac63b46f4acf8b09dbc5e17b7.png);
  height: 575px;
  width: 361px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="switchSel">
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="brown">brown</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="switch black">
  <div class="back">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for replying, however, wouldn't it take alot of code to manually insert every image in and the background of the switches needs to be changed too on selection. Is there any way to fix that? I am new to it and I'd appreciate any guidance.

Comment: There is a way.. You can keep a constant image and just change the hue of the image using css `filter`. Read more about it [here](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/functions/hue-rotate). But i would suggest changing the image. If image is too simple then create a png without any color and change the background color. Accept answers if it helped :)

Comment: I have tried filters but it doesn't seem to work. Perhaps my method of implication is wrong. The images of the switches change, thanks to you, but I need the back images to change too just like shown in the example site. I tried modifying the code you suggested to make it do both and unfortunately, it doesn't seem to like me. Is there any way we can link the back images too just like the button image? You've been really helpful.

Comment: Try not to ghost out when dealing with something. Not going to earn you much points.