# Selected images changing and displayed together from two different dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'd like to make something of this kind where you can select the fore and background and make it display together based on what you have selected: https://www.control4.com/solutions/products/switches

NOTE: Both the images would be selected from dropdown and should be displayed together after selection. I have managed to get one bit working but I am struggling with changing the background and displaying it with the foreground.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>                 
<div>
    <h3>Buttons</h3>
    <select id="switchSel">
      <option value="black">Black</option>
      <option value="brown">Brown</option>
      <option value="white">White</option>
      <option value="aluminum">Aluminum</option>
      <option value="biscuit">Biscuit</option>
      <option value="snowwhite">Snow White</option>
      <option value="midnightblack">Midnight Black</option>
      <option value="lightalmond">Light Almond</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="switch black">
    <div class="back">
        <!-- <select id="faceplate">
          <option value="backblack" class="backblack">Black</option>
          <option value="backbrown">Brown</option>
          <option value="backwhite">white</option>
          <option value="backbiscuit">Biscuit</option>
          <option value="backblack">Black</option>
          <option value="backblack">Black</option>
       </select>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.back {
    background: url(switch/faceplate/white.png);
    height: 575px;
    width: 361px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
}
.backblack {
    -webkit-filter: saturate(110);
    filter: saturate(0);
}
.brown {
    background: url(switch/button/brown.png);
    height: 575px;
    width: 361px;
}
.black {
    background: url(switch/button/black.png);
    height: 575px;
    width: 361px;
}
.white {background: url(switch/button/white.png);
    height: 575px;
    width: 361px;
}
.aluminum {background: url(switch/button/aluminum.png);
    height: 575px;
    width: 361px;
}
.snowwhite {background: url(switch/button/snowwhite.png);
    height: 575px;
    width: 361px;
}
.lightalmond {background: url(switch/button/lightalmond.png);
    height: 575px;
    width: 361px;
}
.midnightblack {background: url(switch/button/midnightblack.png);
    height: 575px;
    width: 361px;
}
.biscuit {background: url(switch/button/biscuit.png);
    height: 575px;
    width: 361px;
}
```

Comment: Just a small word of advice, you're repeating a lot of CSS when you don't need to. You're repeating the width and height attribute onto each colour, whereas you could just have one class to define the size, and then add classes for each colour.

Comment: To help you we need your javascript-code

Comment: Apologies for forgetting it. A fellow programmer suggested this and the css bits. <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#switchSel, faceplate').change(function() {

                var switchPic = $('.switch');
                switchPic.removeClass();
                switchPic.addClass('switch ' + $(this).val());
              })
            })
      </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the class on an element when the select box changes, you can use this simple bit of jQuery to change the classname. The only problem with this approach is that you'd also have to remove the old classname each time, or somehow reset it.

To avoid this problem, you could instead store the colour value in an attribute, and target it using the attribute selector. This way, you can easily just update the value.

```
var front = $('.front');
var back = $('.back');

$('#front').on('change', function(e){
  front.attr('data-colour', $(this).val());
});

$('#back').on('change', function(e){
  back.attr('data-colour', $(this).val());
});
```

This would change the data attribute value when you changed the select value. You could then style each one using something like this:

```
[data-colour="brown"]{
    background: brown url('switch/button/brown.png');
}
```

Here's a codepen which explains the concept further.

http://codepen.io/SudoCat/pen/yVjjLx?editors=1111

Comment: Hey there, this seems to make sense and I do understand what you meant here. I tried putting this code into my html project and the images won't overlap. For instance, if I select a back, only the selected back would display and the selected front would not be displayed. Would there be any way around this?

Comment: That's just down to your CSS - all you would need to do is position your "front" correctly above the "back". It's slightly hard to tell you exactly what you need without knowing what assets you're using.

Comment: That's okay, how am I supposed to show you the assets? I'd appreciate if you could help me get this working.

Comment: Post them online somewhere? Provide a screenshot of what you are currently looking at? From what you're saying, it almost sounds like you aren't using transparent PNGs, which means that the top image would hide the background image.
I have updated the Codepen link to display a clearer working example, utilising transparent background PNG/SVG images for the front section. This should provide all the information you need to get it working.
http://codepen.io/SudoCat/pen/yVjjLx

Comment: This is amazing and I can't thank you enough for your time and effort. I did use the example you recently provided, however, there are still issues. It displays images as shown in the image and I have also provided screenshot of the png images that I got directly from the reference website.  - https://postimg.org/image/xpmjcl60x/

Comment: Ahha! I see what you mean; That should be easy for you to fix - Just remove the background colours (I just put those there to show that something was changing). Sorry for the delayed reply, had to fix my own bugs ;)

Comment: I hope your project is going well and fantastic! I altered the position too so it fits in the middle, however, just one last thing is if we can do anything about the corners? The button is supposed to be seen through the empty space in the faceplate. I tried positioning the button at the back so it shows through but I suppose I did it the wrong way. I have included example in the image for your reference. Please see example 1.0 - postimg.org/image/ejc3bkp6l

Comment: By the looks of it, that's just the background colour. You should be able to easily remove that, just change: `[data-colour="white"] {
  background: white url(switch/button/white.png);
}` to `[data-colour="white"] {
  background: url(switch/button/white.png);
}`

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange. As long as the images on top have a transparent background and there's no background colour on the containing element, then I can't think why that would happen. try adding `.front { background-color: transparent !important }` just to make sure that it's not gaining a background from somewhere. (Warning: Generally speaking, try to avoid using !important in production unless you absolutely have to)

Comment: I asked the question previously and the answer I got seemed to work perfectly with the same images I am using now. The only problem was that I couldn't change the back, and only the buttons. I'd be really grateful if you could have a look at the code that was provided and see if we can incorporate that in the current code. I can't be thankful enough, Robin. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994568/image-overlay-and-change-on-dropdown-selection/40995114#40995114

Comment: Try not to ghost out when dealing with something. Not going to earn you much points.

Comment: Apologies, unfortunately I hadn't really had the time to deal with this any further - The example I have provided already provides all of the functionality you were struggling with. If you read through the code you've been provided and did some further research on it, you should have been able to get it working fine. I did my best to help you, and provided a fairly succinct answer to your problem; There's no need to be rude when someone doesn't get an opportunity to reply to you.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. As I mentioned, I already asked this before here and didn't receive much help. It is frustrating to not know a language and being stuck with it for weeks, the feeling of helplessness sinks in. But you have been helpful indeed. No harm intended. I apologise for any wrong impression and thank you once again.

Comment: That's understandable, it's never fun to be stuck! It's quite hard for me to decipher exactly where your problem is occurring, is it possible for you to recreate it in codepen/jsfiddle? edit: although I don't know if you can post links at your reputation level, but I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: That's okay. I managed to make some basic changes and got it working at an acceptable level. I really should focus on getting better grip at languages. Thanks alot, Robin.

Comment: Glad to hear you managed to get it back on track! Good luck with your learning - it can be a damn pain trying to get your head around it all, but it's invaluable once you get it down.

Comment: Thank you. Any tips/suggestions or advice for a beginner?